# Comparison between parse html and text using jquery

Tags: jquery

I just want to know that is it possible to compare parse html and normal text?

I will just give brief explanation about my problem:

I have a scenario where I have to count no.of characters as '10' from html

```
eg: <p style="font-family:verdana">What is the advantage of jquery</p>
```

If I count this html I cant take exact characters of text and I need to take only 10 characters and I have to display the remaining characters separately as two variables as follows where I should not lose the paragraph style in the second variable.

```
eg: var one = "What is th";
    var two = "<p style="font-family:verdana">e advantage of jquery</p>";
```

If I use .parse(),can I use to compare with the normal text,I dont know the exact answer how to proceed,If any one had idea,can you suggest me how to do by giving sample code?

Or is there any possible to show like the following:

```
eg: var one = "<p style="font-family:verdana">What is th</p>";
    var two = "<p style="font-family:verdana">e advantage of jquery</p>";
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No idea what you're trying to achieve. After parsing, the `p` element contains a text node with contents "What is the advantage of jquery". You can cut this text into pieces of 10 characters and put those into other elements, but what does this have to do with your question title?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var html = '<p style="font-family:verdana">What is the advantage of jquery</p>';
var text = jQuery(html).text();
var one = '<p style="font-family:verdana">' + text.substring(0, 10) + '</p>';
var two = '<p style="font-family:verdana">' + text.substring(10) + '</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = '<p style="font-family:verdana">What is the advantage of jquery</p>';

// convert HTML string to two jQuery objects
var one = $( html ), two = $( html );

// replace the text inside first object with its substring (10 characters starting at 0)
one.text( one.text().substr(0, 10) );

// replace the text inside second object with its substring (the resto of characters starting at 10)
two.text( two.text().substr(10) );

// now you have two jQuery objects, each containing a paragraph with a fragment of text.
console.log( one );
console.log( two );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ApfJz/16/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max = 10;    
    var text = $('#elem').text();

    if(text.length > max){
        var one = text.substring(0, max);
        var short = text.substring(max);
        var clone = $('#elem').clone();
        clone.text(short);

        var temp = $('<div />');
        $(temp).append(clone);

        var two = $(temp).html();
        alert(one);
        alert(two);
    }
});
```